# function return code block query

Tags: php, function, return

Quick question to do with php functions, it may sound silly to some of you but I dont want to get in to bad habits. Is there anything wrong with doing the following?

```
function do_something($val)
{
  $a = 1;
  if ($val==$a)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Instead of;

```
function do_something($val)
{
  $a = 1;
  if ($val==$a)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Sorry guys I think my example isn't great. Basically the function could insert data into a database or send an email etc. With these functions I may only need to now whether it was successful or not by returning true or false.  I wanted to know whether its suitable that I can use the shorter method instead of the if-else block.

I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: maybe just a bad example, but of course this should be just `return $val==$a;`

Comment: If you see an `if-else` which only returns `true` or `false`, then you are certainly overcomplicating thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is perfectly fine, and in fact advised in multiple cases. :)

Answer (score 4):

Not really. Both works the same. However, it would be much cleaner to write it like this:

```
function do_something($val)
{
  $a = 1;
  return ($val==$a) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: `? true : false` after a boolean expression is just confusing and useless

Comment: I know this; Its to help provide him/her with another way of doing simple returns. He might not want to return a bool where `return ($val ==$a)` wouldn't work as intended.

Comment: I think this is more confusing as you don't give a hint what a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is.

Answer (score 2):

That's totally cool, because when returning a value, the function is left and it doesn't matter what follows.

But you could shorten this with

```
function do_something($val)
{
  $a = 1;
  return $val == $a; // this condition will be evaluated to true/false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to do it:

```php
function do_something($val)
{
  return ($val==1) ;
}
```